# iOS Build fails for push notifications while giving build?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

While running the app by connecting directly to Xcode, it executes well and we are able to receive notifications. But while distributing the build via diawi or dropbox by using enterprise Distribution Certificate we get notification error as 
    "Failed Registering for push notifications. no valid apns certificate found"

It was working fine upto last week.

Please refer the screenshot. Checked with Xcode 6.3 and 7.2. But same error exists.

[image: Push notification error]

Please suggest how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different certificates for APNS configuration.

Development Certificate (Sandbox APNS environment) can be used only with development provisioning profile.

Production Certificate (Production environment) will be used along with production provisioning profile.

If you directly install app from Xcode (debug mode) then it will use development profile. If you archive then production provisional profile to distribute from diawi or another medium. You have to use appropriate certificate at server side for APNS implementation.